# Reiniciar función al cambiar tamaño de la pantalla (Windows Resize)

Tags: javascript

Tengo está función, la cual quiero que se reinicie cuando se cambie el tamaño de la ventana del navegador.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
        $(".arrow").fadeIn(1500);
    },7500);
});
```

Adicional a esa función hice esta:

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
        $(".arrow").fadeIn(1500);
    },7500);
});
```

Pero nofunciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar una variable que almacene el identificador de tu `setTimeout` y cada vez que se vuelva a ejecutar la función limpias el `setTimeout` con un `clearInterval` pasandole el ID de ese timer. Con eso tu función quedaría así:

```
let timerId;

$(window).resize(function() {
  if (timerId) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }

  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".arrow").fadeIn(1500);
    },7500);
});
```

Ten en cuenta que la variable del timer tiene que estar en un scope exterior

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó... Ahora no sé como agregar que también muestre la flecha al cargar la página

Answer (score 1):

Puede agregar el evento `addEventListener` para escuchar cada vez que se redimensiona la ventana.

```js
function reportWindowSize (event) {
  console.log(event)
}

window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize);
```